# Having trouble adding text after my XML Root from TSQL to XML

Tags: xml, t-sql

Hi I'm fairly new on converting T-SQL query to XML.  I wrote the following sample query to get an XML output, but my requirement need to have text call "Header/" on the second line after Message Root. My issue was a blank space between the word "Header" and "/".

```
DECLARE @xmlCar xml;
DECLARE @strCar varchar(max);
DECLARE @sxml xml;
SET @xmlCar = (
SELECT 1 AS [@ID] 
    ,(SELECT 123 AS [AddressID]
    ,555 AS [AddressNumber] 
    ,'Somewhere Street' AS [AddressStreet] 
    ,'Nashville' AS [AddressCity] 
    ,'TN' AS [AddressState] 
    ,37115 AS [AddressZip] 
    ,'D2QZ0OLXKG' AS [status_rtk/@ID]
    ,'Institution Tax Status rtk1' AS [status_rtk]
    ,'D2QZ0OO0BF' AS [category_rtk/@ID]
    ,'Inst Facility type rtk1' AS [category_rtk]

FOR XML PATH('AddressDemographic'),ROOT('AddressDemographics'),TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('USER'), ROOT('Message'), TYPE)

SET @sxml = REPLACE(CAST(@xmlCar AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'<Message>','<Message><Header/>')

SELECT @sxml


<Message>
  <Header />
  <USER ID="1">
    <AddressDemographics>
      <AddressDemographic>
        <AddressID>123</AddressID>
        <AddressNumber>555</AddressNumber>
        <AddressStreet>Somewhere Street</AddressStreet>
        <AddressCity>Nashville</AddressCity>
        <AddressState>TN</AddressState>
        <AddressZip>37115</AddressZip>
        <status_rtk ID="D2QZ0OLXKG">Institution Tax Status rtk1</status_rtk>
        <category_rtk ID="D2QZ0OO0BF">Inst Facility type rtk1</category_rtk>
      </AddressDemographic>
    </AddressDemographics>
  </USER>
</Message>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and add your **expected output** to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query might be slightly improved with this, but this is not the answer to your question:

```
DECLARE @xmlCar xml= 
(
 SELECT
    '' AS [Header]
    ,(
        SELECT 1 AS [@ID] 
            ,123 AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/AddressID]
            ,555 AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/AddressNumber] 
            ,'Somewhere Street' AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/AddressStreet] 
            ,'Nashville' AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/AddressCity] 
            ,'TN' AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/AddressState] 
            ,37115 AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/AddressZip] 
            ,'D2QZ0OLXKG' AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/status_rtk/@ID]
            ,'Institution Tax Status rtk1' AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/status_rtk]
            ,'D2QZ0OO0BF' AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/category_rtk/@ID]
            ,'Inst Facility type rtk1' AS [AddressDemographic/AddressDemographics/category_rtk]
        FOR XML PATH('USER'), TYPE
     )
 FOR XML PATH('Message')
);

SELECT @xmlCar
```

What you really asked was this

> My issue was a blank space between the word "Header" and "/"

In your own attempt you use a string method to introduce `<Header/>` to your XML. When you look at it, there is a blank coming from nowhere and that is disturbing you...

The answer is: **This is of no meaning at all**

I don't know, why this blank matters in your case, but it shouldn't...

XML is not stored as text internally, rather as kind of a tree. What you see, is just the transcription of this, to get it readable for you.

Look at this example

```
    SELECT CAST('<root><test><![CDATA[Content with forbidden characters <<>> &]]></test></root>' AS XML)
```

This is implicitly translated to

```
<root>
  <test>Some Content with forbidden characters &lt;&lt;&gt;&gt; &amp;</test>
</root>
```

You see what I mean? **XML is not just text with extra characters...**

So the answer is:

Your `<Header />` element is semantically identical with `<Header/>`. How this is **displayed to the user** is not your desicion.

The **only way to enforce this** is on string level, but I would not advise this. In this case just use my query and add

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(@xmlCar AS nvarchar(MAX)),'<Header />','<Header/>')
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo for detail explanation.